# Writing 1 line of a string from Position1 to end of line (not String) in JAVA

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a String of 200 Lines and I searched from the String if specific word is present at which position and then to write only that line of string to a variable not any of the other lines.
I am using subString method but stuck at the end of line.

```
pos = docText.indexOf("ABC");
String known = docText.substring(pos+28 , *end of line*);
```

How to denote this *end of line*

Comment: You can first split line by \n and then do for loop and inside for loop use same check to search substring

Comment: Personally I would probably use a Scanner on the string and call nextLine until you get to the one with the substring in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, but the simplest solution, in my opinion, is to loop over characters following your search text.
I assume 28 is the length of your search text, so you can find the rest of the line using something like this

```
StringBuilder restOfLine = new StringBuilder();
char nextChar;
for (int i = pos + 28; (nextChar = docText.charAt(i)) != '\n'; i++)
    restOfLine.append(nextChar);

String known = restOfLine.toString();
```

As an alternative, and if you're already using commons-lang, you can use

```
String known = StringUtils.substringBetween(docText, "ABC", "\n");
```

Just remember to use the proper character for the end of line (I used `\n` in the examples)